# How to search the text of child nodes within a parent node in a Treeview control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have a Treeview control structure which I generate in run time, which adds child nodes with text taken from a textbox to a parent node with the click of dedicated buttons.

Now, as more child nodes are added to a particular parent node, I would like to search the names (text) of previously added child nodes within that parent node with the click of a button to keep the user from adding duplicate nodes with the same name.

If this happens, the user should receive a message that a child node with the same name has already been added to that particular parent node. I have written a code that addresses this issue for child nodes next to each other, i.e. if the user adds a child node called “Frank” to a parent node called “Family” and then tries to add “Frank” again immediately after wards, he/she will get the message that “Frank” has already been added to the “Family” parent node.

My problem is that if the user adds “Frank”, then adds “Shelly”, then “Mark”, then adds “Frank” again, he/she will not get the message. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Add the code you have written and reformat your question to be a little clearer about your expectations vs. what is actually being output in your solution.

Comment: Hello Steve, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my original post as I am sure you would have been able to help me with my problem. In the meantime, ChicagoMike has helped me solve the issue. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Iki - Please add your code next time.

Comment: @Enigmativity Hello, my friend. Kindly forgive my systematic error. In the meantime, I have a new problem which I am hoping you could help me with. Could you kindly check my profile and see my latest problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to get the Parent Node for the child node that was just entered, retrieve all the child nodes from that parent node and then iterate through the child nodes to see if any of those nodes have the same name.

It might go something like this:

```
    Dim currentNode As TreeNode = TreeView1.SelectedNode ' The node we just entered
    Dim targetName As String = TextBox1.Text.trim.toLower ' The string we're searching against - we trim and set to lower for comparison purposes

    Dim parentNode = currentNode.Parent ' Get the parent
    Dim childNodes As TreeNodeCollection = parentNode.Nodes ' Get all the children 

    Dim WeHaveDuplicate as Boolean = False ' We use this to flag if a duplicate is found.  Initially set to false.

    For Each tempNode As TreeNode In childNodes
        If tempNode.Text.trim.toLower = targetName Then WeHaveDuplicate = True ' Test that we have the same name but not referring to the same node
    Next

    If WeHaveDuplicate= True Then 
       ' Send message to user
       ' Do not add new node to treeview 
    Else
       ' Add new node to treeview
    End If;
```

UPDATE: I modified this code to use the textbox text, instead of the current value of the selected node, to determine whether a match exists.

Comment: @ ChicagoMike: Thank you for your reply. Your suggestion is very much appreciated and really useful. However, if it is not to much to ask, please how would you suggest I re-work your idea if I was check the textbox text (which feeds into the node) before adding it to the Treeview? Thanks once again.

Comment: I'll try - do you know which node you're going to be adding that text to? In other words, has the user at least selected the node they are going to add the text to?

Comment: @ ChicgoMike: Thank you for replying to me. Yes, please assume that the user has selected the parent node to which they want to add a new child node whose text is from the textbox. So, the task for the code would be to check if a node with the same text has already been created/added under the selected parent node. If true, then the code sends a message to the user, and does not add a new child node. But if false; then a new child node whose text is from the textbox is added to the parent node.Thank you for taking the time to help me. I appreciate your assistance a lot.

Comment: @ ChicagoMike: Many thanks for your help! I've able to solve the problem through studying your most valuable insights and a little thought on my part. You are a life saver. I wouldn't have been able to solve this, this quickly if not for your help.
What I did in the end was begin the sub by declaring a variable to represent the selected node like you have suggested in your update; then pretty much followed through your update; i.e. 
Dim SelectedTreeNode As TreeNode = Treeview1. SelectedNode 
Dim currentNode As TreeNode = SelectedTreeNode.Nodes.Add(TextBox8.Text) …etc

Thanks again.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I've able to solve the problem through studying your most valuable insights and a little thought on my part. You are a life saver. I wouldn't have been able to solve this, this quickly if not for your help. What I did in the end was begin the sub by declaring a variable to represent the selected node like you have suggested in your update; then pretty much followed through your update; i.e. Dim SelectedTreeNode As TreeNode = Treeview1. SelectedNode Dim currentNode As TreeNode = SelectedTreeNode.Nodes.Add(TextBox8.Text) …etc Thanks again.